# How to allocate separate parts of a LaTex document to several distinct parts in a uniform file?

Tags: sectioning, packages, labels, subfiles

Hello dear readers and researchers,
I have begun learning La-Tex and I want to divide the main file into several section in separate sub sections of a uniform La-Tex project (pardon me for that I am not familiar with the field's jargon language).
More specifically, I want the preamble as a separate section, with proper coding to allocate different parts Ex. Introduction, Literature and et. as exclusive separate sub-sections of the main file, the preamble. So that I can work on each part separately with less confusion that otherwise is very likely.
I tried to read a few instructions like those made by Overleaf, but I found it a little complicating. In my understanding I need to educate the preamble (WHICH IS MY QUESTION, HOW?) then recall each section with \section and \label.
Thank you very much for your consideration

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents would be a good introduction to this topic. Note that `\section` and `\label` are both unrelated to subdividing files, and `\section` is not (so much) related to `\label`. For `\section` see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_commands, and for `\label` see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing.

Comment: note it is LaTeX not La-teX . Your question is not very clear but you can split the source file up into multiple files eg one per section and `\input` them in to the main document.

Comment: Thank you Marjin for your help, time and energy.

Comment: Thank you David Carlisle